# NewtonsoftJson being accepted in ASP.NET core 3.0 rc1 application

Tags: json, asp.net-core

This is more of a 'why is .NET okay with this?' kind of question. The documentation for migrating to 3.0 said to that NewtonsoftJson is no longer built into the shared framework.

I have a couple libraries that are netstandard2.0 which use Newtonsoft.json package in which my 3.0 application is dependent. However, I am getting no complaints from my 3.0 application by just using `using Newtonsoft.Json` in the file. I don't have the recommended 3.0 Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package in the 3.0 project file either.

[This article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/) mentions using the `System.Text.Json` NuGet package in .netstandard projects. Should I be doing this then?

Comment: It's just a transitive dependency. Because your ASP.NET Core project references a project that references JSON.NET, it's available to it.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot! I’m gonna stick with Newtonsoft for now! Appreciate the clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Core Mvc no longer uses `Newtonsoft.Json` as the default json serializer but, it could still be enabled with:

1. Install the package with `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson --version 3.0.0-rc1.19457.4`
2. Add `AddNewtonsoftJson()` after `AddMvc()`, `AddControllers()`, `AddRazorPages()`, or `AddControllersWithViews()`.

`System.Text.Json` is recommended as default but there is no reason for ASP.NET Core to disallow you to use`Newtonsoft.Json`, it just does not include or use it as default.

You could continue to use `Newtonsoft.Json` in your .NET Standard 2.0 library project, but for better performance, you could install the package with `dotnet add package System.Text.Json --version 4.6.0-rc1.19456.4` and migrate all uses of `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json`. But note that `System.Text.Json` is still very new and not as full-featured as `Newtonsoft.Json`, and some behavior would differ.